# using substr to limit characters inside of an element

Tags: jquery, substring

I am paginating users and in my view I have:

```
<li class="profile">
  <%= user.profile %> 
</li>
```

I want to limit `li.profile` to 200 characters followed by three dots `'...'`

Below does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("li.profile").each(function(){
       if ($(this).html().length > 200) {
           $(this).html($(this).html().substr(0, 200)); 
            $(this).append('...');
        }
    });
});
```

[image: from developer tools]

this is the way it looks in developer tools.

css

```
li.profile {
font-size: 14px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.text()`; `.html()` sets `.innerHTML` of element, not `.textContent`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("li.profile").each(function(){
       if (this.textContent.length > 200) {
           $(this).text(function(_, text) {
             return text.substr(0, 200).concat("..."); 
           })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Strangely, this is resulting in a length of 3 characters, I suppose 0-2 instead of 0-200. `30 ...` and `"[I...` and `I l...`

Comment: _"Strangely, this is resulting in a length of 3 characters"_ Can you create stacksnippets or jsfiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: it works in jfiddle. I had changed the code from 200 to 20 when I made my first comment.... and then tested different numbers... each time it is acting as if there are 14 invisible characters before the text starts.. which has to be `user.profile`

Comment: which is weird cause it is not shown in developer tools or the source code.

Comment: _"which is weird cause it is not shown in developer tools or the source code."_ Are there space characters within `li.profile` text?

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss Images of code are usually not helpful; though you can see what was occurring. Space characters increment `.length` of `.textContent`